# Difference Between Synchronous and Asychnchronus I/O

Tags: operating-system

I have been learning the internals of an operating system and I am confused as to what the basic difference between synchronous and asynchronous I/O is.
How does an operating system know whether it is synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Synchronous I/O mean that some flow of execution (such as a process or thread) is waiting for the operation to complete. Asynchronous I/O means that nothing is waiting for the operation to complete and the completion of the operation itself causes something to happen.

Synchronous I/O -- some execution vehicle (like a process or thread) that initiates the I/O also waits for the I/O to complete (and perhaps completes it). When the I/O completes, that same execution vehicle goes on to do something else, perhaps using the results of the I/O.

Example:

```
int i = read (file_handle, buffer, length);
if (i <= 0)
      return;
// handle results
```

Here, the `read` operation starts a read from the file. The same thread that calls `read` gets the return value when the read operation completes and can process the result.

Asynchronous I/O -- no execution vehicle waits for the I/O to complete. When the I/O completes, whatever execution vehicle happens to complete the I/O may arrange for later things to happen.

Example:

```
async_read (file_handle, buffer, length, completion_handler);
// do other stuff having nothing to do with the read

...

completion_handler(int count)
{
    if (count < 0)
         return;
    // handle results
}
```

Here, the call to `async_read` starts the read operation. The thread that started the operation can go on to do other things entirely. When the operation completes, the implementation calls `completion_handler` (possibly by another thread) which gets the results of the operation.

Generally the operating system doesn't have to know which is which. You can, for example, implement only asynchronous operations and have the completion handler unblock the synchronous thread. Usually, deep under the hood, they all look the same with some piece of code called when the operation completes that does whatever has to be done.

You can easily turn either into the other.

If you have only asynchronous operations and want a synchronous operation, just call the asynchronous operation and then block on something that is unblocked by the completion handler.

If you have only synchronous operations and want an asynchronous operation, just create a new thread to call the synchronous operation and have it invoke the completion handler when the synchronous operation returns.

Comment: Awesome answer!